# Android icon not showing Correctly as in preview

Tags: android, adaptive-icon

Actually, the problem is the icon in the preview. It is showing changes when I change the size, but it is not affecting the icon of my test device. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please ask question with proper explaination..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use all these standerd formats and Don't Create 9-patch images for launcher icons .

```
hdpi=281*164
mdpi=188*110
xhdpi=375*219
xxhdpi=563*329
xxxhdpi=750*438

48 × 48 (mdpi)
72 × 72 (hdpi)
96 × 96 (xhdpi)
144 × 144 (xxhdpi)
192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)
512 × 512 (Google Play store)
```